# How do I make Vuforia image targets work with MRTK 3?

Tags: c#, vuforia, mrtk, magic-leap

I'm trying to get a Magic Leap 2 project to work with both MRTK 3 and Vuforia. If I use the MRTK XR Rig camera and add Vuforia Behaviour to it, image target objects will appear properly aligned for a split second the first time the device sees the image target. They then disappear and never show up again unless I lose tracking and regain it, at which point they show up for a split second again.

I read online that making the near clipping plane of the camera substantially smaller (like 0.0001) is supposed to fix that but it's not working for me. Do you have any suggestions how I can get Vuforia to work with MRTK 3?

I should add that the image target objects are visible and properly aligned in the camera preview window, they just stop rendering instantly in-game.

//Stefan

Tried to make Vuforia image targets work with MRTK 3. Tried using both an AR camera with a Vuforia Behaviour component and using the MRTK XR Rig Camera with Vuforia Behaviour. Neither worked.

Comment: Do older MRTK versions (e.g, 2.8) work for you? If no then this is likely an OpenXR configuration issue.