# MRTK 3 with Vuforia problem for Image Target Recognition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, hololens

I want to create a Unity app for Hololens 2 which will use MRTK 3 and Vuforia for Image Targeting. I tried to attach the Vuforia Behaviour and DefaultInitializationErrorHandler scripts to the main camera of the MRTK XR Rig (also configured the camera and other stuff as in this [link](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/66)) and then added an Image Target. When I try to recognize the image while in play mode or deployed on Hololens I have the next behaviour:
My image is recognized well and my gameobject which must appear above the image is displaying just for a small ammount of time and then it is going somewhere very far and I cannot see where it is. What can be the problem? In the logs I see that my image is targeted normally.
My situation is like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563034/how-do-i-make-vuforia-image-targets-work-with-mrtk-3) post on the stackoverflow.

I tried to make the default recommended setup for mrtk and vuforia and also tried to add Vuforia AR Camera as the setup for other devices which are not using MRTK

Comment: Hi OxM, which versions of Unity, OpenXR and MRTK3 are you using? Also, are you sure that the camera Y offset and the position of the CameraOffset GameObject are set to 0 and don't change?

Comment: As pointed out by @ptc-epassaro, this likely seems to be an offset problem. Have you tried to follow the steps described e.g. in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77746813/17438972)?

Comment: Hi @ptc-epassaro I am using Unity 2022.3.17f1, MRTK3 (the latest versions for all packages) and OpenXR Plugin 1.10.0. This are the latest for now from the Microsoft MR Feature Tool).

Comment: @anjelomerte  Regarding the steps described in the link you provided I tried to implement as the first solution I found and its not working for me. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your logs, is the gameobject just offset at a constant distance or not?

Comment: I found now that it has somehow a constant offset and also observed the next behaviour: 
 When object is first tracked or is changing status from NO_POSE to TRACKED--NORMAL for a very small ammount of time I can see my gameobject like it has to be, but when it disappears and trying to find by changing it's position I can see it but is scaled as a very small gameobject and also tracking is working very strange, if I move my Image Target up, my gameobject is going to the right for example.

Comment: @OxM thanks for the update. Can I ask you to please open a new issue on the Vuforia GitHub repository? https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues
This is a behaviour we have never observed so far, so any further information could help us reproduce this issue and would be very much appreciated. If possible, it would be really useful if you could also share your Scene hierarchy.

Comment: Are the dimensions you specified for the image target identical to the actual dimensions of the image target?

Comment: @anjelomerte Yes, I thinked about this too and recreated the database with the real dimensions and the behaviour was the same, but I managed which was the problem, I described it below for the ptc-epassaro question. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: @ptc-epassaro I managed to find which is the problem. In the main camera of the MRTK XR Rig is a component named "Tracked Pose Driver" which have a parameter called "Update Type". By default its value is Update and Before Render and if its changed to just Update, then the problem is gone. But my concenrs about this is at what cost is this solution and how it will be projected to the app when it will be populatedd with many targets and gameobjects. Since I am somehow new to unity and AR dev I cant figure by my self right now. If you can please explain where this solution can lead.

Comment: @ptc-epassaro I added a new issue [here](https://github.com/PTCInc/vuforia-engine/issues/108)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the solution was that in the Main Camera of the MRTK XR Rig is a component called "Tracked Pose Driver" which has a parameter named "Update Type" and its value must be changed from the default "Update And before Render" to just "Update" as in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz4Zi.png) screenshot.

Edit:
Since Unity is recommending that the value for the "Update Type" parameter to be "Update And before Render" this solution is not the best even if it is getting to the desired result. With the help of @ptc-epassaro figured out that the best solution is just to disable the MRTK Input Simulator from Scene while testing Vuforia functionalities.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).